# Canvas - Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the below error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
>       at draw (app.js:68)

Line 68 is `let snakeX = snake[0].x;`. Here is my code:

```
const cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

// create the unit
const box = 32;

// load img / audio
let ground = new Image();
ground.src = "img/ground.png";

const foodImg = new Image();
foodImg.src = "img/food.png"

// creat the snake
let snake = [];

snake[0] = {
    x: 9 * box,
    y: 10 * box
};

// create the food
let food = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 17 + 1) * box,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 15 + 3) * box
}

// create the score var
let score = 0;

// control the snake
let d;

document.addEventListener("keydown", direciton);

function direciton(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        d = "LEFT";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        d = "UP";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        d = "RIGHT";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        d = "DOWN";
    }
}

// draw everything  to the canvas
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);
    for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = (i == 0) ? "green" : "white";
        ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, box, box);

        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, box, box);
    }
    ctx.drawImage(foodImg, food.x, food.y);

    //old head position
    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;

    //which direction
    if (d = "LEFT") snakeX -= box;
    if (d = "UP") snakeY -= box;
    if (d = "RIGHT") snakeX += box;
    if (d = "DOWN") snakeY += box;
    //remove the tail
    snake.pop();
    // add new Head
    let newHead = {
        x: snakeX,
        y: snakeY
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "45px Changa one";
    ctx.fillText(score, 2 * box, 1.6 * box);
}

// call draw function every 100ms
let game = setInterval(draw, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the object newHead to your snake array.

You need to add:

```
snake.push(newHead)
```

After you define it.